# access and manipulating variables inside directives that create scopes angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller in AngularJS and a view which goal is to create an auto-complete dropdown. I have some issues with the functionality. I start typing and the options show under the input but I want to click on one of them and the input's value to change and the suggestions' list to disappear. This is not happening at the moment.

This is my controller:

```
$http.get(API_URL + "get/cities")
    .then(function (response) {
            $scope.cities = response.data;
        },
        function () {
            console.log('error');
        });

$scope.selectCity = function (cityId, name) {
    $scope.citySearch = name;
    $scope.showCityList = false;
};
```

And here is the view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" ng-model="citySearch" ng-change="showCityList = true" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Град">
            <ul ng-if="citySearch.length > 0 && showCityList" class="list-group">
                <li ng-repeat="city in cities | filter: citySearch | orderBy:'name'" class="list-group-item" ng-click="selectCity(city.id, city.name)">@{{ city.name }}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I should mention that this HTML code is placed inside of a ng-switch-when.

Comment: it seems to do what you want! could you please explain the problem even more?

Comment: if I click on one of the options the value of the input doesn't change and the <ul> doesn't disappear

Comment: It seems to do that, can you check this [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/3zm06dxh/)

Comment: I forgot to mention that this html is inside of an switch case, i will edit the question right away

Comment: Could you please replicate the issue in the JSFiddle I provided, so that I can work with the issue directly?

Comment: I think I updated it

Comment: You need to click on fork after loggin in and share the link of it here

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gospodinove/8b1ru26e/ there it is

Comment: New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view`, `ng-include` and `ng-if` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved. This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models.

Comment: what does that mean? and I am definitely new to AngularJS haha

Comment: @dinkogosp Simply up, `ng-switch` and `ng-if` will create a new scope, so the updates from elements inside the `ng-if` or `ng-switch` will not propagate to the main parent controller. Thus you are getting the issue, to solve this you can use `$parent` to update the variable at the main controller instead, anyway here is the [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Kai_Draord/qtbvLcxo/)  Read more about this issue [here](http://www.lorenzomarcon.com/2014/07/ng-ifng-switch-breaks-ng-model-no-its-just-a-matter-of-understanding-scopes/)